# Using RowFilter on datagridview and trying to filter multiple string names

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, filter

I am trying to filter multiple string names on one datagridview. I am appending the filter string like so

```
                filter = " (DateTime >= #" + startDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "# And DateTime <= #"
                    + endDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "#";
                for (int i = 0; i < productNumber.Count; i++)
                {
                    filter += " And TagIndex ='" + productNumber[i] + "'";
                }
                filter += " )";
```

where productNumber is a List with the ID tags in it in string format. The output is something like this:

(DateTime >= #11/02/2014 01:00:58# And DateTime <= #12/01/2014 00:00:00# And TagIndex ='0' And TagIndex ='1' And TagIndex ='2' )

I'm getting a Syntax Error when I try to pass this a the filter for the datagridview.

Comment: I believe I figured it out it should be:
                                                                                                                                            filter = " (DateTime >= #" + startDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "# And DateTime <= #"
                    + endDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "# And TagIndex IN (";
                 for (int i = 0; i < productNumber.Count; i++)
                {
                    filter += productNumber[i] + ", ";
                }
                filter += " ))";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to initialize filters for every instance of the tagname. The code is as follows:

```
                for (int oh = 0; oh < productIndexes.Count; oh++)
                {
                    if (oh == 0)
                    {
                        filter += "(DateTime >= #" + startDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "# And DateTime <= #"
                            + endDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "#)" + " And (TagIndex = '" + productIndexes[oh] + "'";
                        indexFilter = "(;Tagname = '" + productIndexes[oh] + "'";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filter += " And (DateTime >= #" + startDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "# And DateTime <= #"
                    + endDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "#)" + " Or TagIndex ='" + productIndexes[oh] + "'";
                        indexFilter += " Or ;Tagname = '" + productIndexes[oh] + "'";
                    }
                }
                filter += " )";
                indexFilter += " )";
                Console.WriteLine(filter);
                Console.WriteLine(indexFilter);
```

forgive the poor naming convention for the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that your filter is not returning anything.  Try changing the last **ANDs** with **ORs** so your filter will look like this `(DateTime >= #11/02/2014 01:00:58# And DateTime <= #12/01/2014 00:00:00# And TagIndex ='0' Or TagIndex ='1' Or TagIndex ='2')`

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I thought I was going to need to use the IN comparison. But this worked beautifully.